# Kafka node timeout connecting to Zookeeper in docker-compose

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-zookeeper

I have this simple docker-compose for running Kafka node and Zookeeper locally.

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    container_name: zookeeper
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    ports:
      - 22181:2181
  
  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 29092:29092
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
```

Kafka node timeouts and exits with the following error:

```
ERROR Timed out waiting for connection to Zookeeper server [zookeeper:2181]. (io.confluent.admin.utils.ClusterStatus)

kafka-kafka-1  | org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SessionTimeoutException: Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 40008ms for session id 0x0
kafka-kafka-1  |        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1258)

kafka-kafka-1 exited with code 1
```

I don't understand why

UPDATE:
Happens only on Ubuntu. Tried the same docker-compose on Win10 and there was no Timeout

Comment: Have you tried to perform this change `KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:22181`?

Comment: @AlexandreJuma Docker services in the same network should not use the host forward port.